# Unity3D not running on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, unity, wine, license

I want to run Unity3d in my 14.04 via Wine.

I installed Unity3d for windows from it's official website but when I try to run **Unity 5.0.0f4 (64-bit).exe** it shows me this message.

[image]

I found one same question on the AskUbuntu, it suggested to enter licence key and re-configuring wine. I tried that twice too but I still get this message.

How can I run Unity3d?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but it doesn't work on Wine anymore - [check the second answer here at this link.](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/146714/how-can-i-run-it-on-linux.html)

> answered Nov 20, 2012 at 10:48 PM by tyjkenn:
>   Unity3d stopped working
>   in WINE from 3.4.2 and onward. Ironically, as Unity pushes for more
>   support for Linux publishing, the Editor works less and less on Linux.
>   With Unity 4, it can't even initialize the license system in WINE.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so now I must install Windows to run Unity!?

Comment: I'm afraid so. Unless you're willing to switch to Blender or another software. It's really the only Achilles' heel of Linux - some games, Photoshop and for now Unity3D. Really wish the developers would give Linux some love too.

Answer (score 1):

Unity3d linux build is now available. download it from here [unity3d linux build](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/08/unity3d-linux-build), download the .deb file and install,its simple.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the information. I'll go for it surely

Answer (score 0):

I've just installed `unity3d` on on my laptop, I'm running 64-bit `ubuntu 14.04`, I downloaded the package from this [blog](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/08/26/unity-comes-to-linux-experimental-build-now-available/) post actually it's the official `unity3d` package for `ubuntu` you can read more info in that blog post.
Download that package and install it via `terminal`, I've tried to installed it via `Ubuntu Software Center` but that was not working as expected, so download the package and do

```
sudo apt-get install lib32gcc1 lib32stdc++6 libc6-i386
sudo dpkg -i unity-editor-5.1.0f3+2015082501_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
```

After this `Unity3d` should be available in the system.